# Getting images from parse on correct order

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to get some strings and one photo from parse.com for tableview. I have an NSObject for this class and also an array of object to store them. I can get the newsTitle and the newsDetail in correct order by got fail when try to get newsPhoto. I suppose it lost its order when try get get images in block. Does anybody know what should I change on below code to fix it?

```
 func getNews(){

    let query = PFQuery(className: "bulletinOnParse")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (allNews: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            var duyuru:News

            for news in allNews! {

                duyuru = News()

                let nTitle = news.objectForKey("title") as! String
                duyuru.newsTitle = nTitle

                let nDetail = news.objectForKey("comment") as! String
                duyuru.newsDetail = nDetail

                let imageFile = news["newsphoto"] as! PFFile
                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData = imageData {
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                            duyuru.newsPhoto = image!
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.bulletin += [duyuru]
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("\(error!.userInfo)")
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

And cellForRowAtIndexPath method below

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DuyuruTableViewCell
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 100

    let cellInfo = bulletin[indexPath.row]

    cell.newsTitle.text = cellInfo.newsTitle
    cell.news.text = cellInfo.newsDetail

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        cell.newsPhoto.image = cellInfo.newsPhoto
    })
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I also try to use an array of UIImage to store the images but couldnt load on correct order. Photos saved on wrong rows.

Comment: The code looks like it's saving the images where they belong.  I imagine what you're seeing is the images being presented strangely in the table view.  Its not a complete answer, but to start, move `self.tableView.reloadData()` to happen after the image is received.  (right after `duyuru.newsPhoto = image!`)

Comment: The code will call in getDataInBackgroundWithBlock as much as allNews.count, so I suppose it may not be a good idea, it will reloadData multiple times. Also I tried and that didn't change anything. Thanks.

Comment: you can achieve it by fetch only PFFile means only imageName("newsphoto") in getNews(). then write  `imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {}` in UITableview `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of how I solve the problem;

First I created an image array from PFFile object

```
var resultUserImageFiles = [PFFile]()
```

Then I get the name and add the array on getNews() method

```
self.resultUserImageFiles.append(news.objectForKey("newsphoto") as! PFFile)
```

And I get each photo for cell on below method in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
self.resultUserImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.newsPhoto.image = image
        }
    }
```